# Getting Started in Docker

Tags: docker, docker-machine

When trying to input the command:

```
docker run -d -p 80:80 docker/getting-started
```

I get an output of:

> Unable to find image 'docker/getting-started:latest' locally
> latest: Pulling from docker/getting-started
> 188c0c94c7c5: Pulling fs layer
> 617561f33ec6: Pulling fs layer
> 7d856acdaa9c: Pulling fs layer
> a0d3c6e28e6d: Waiting
> af69a9b963c8: Waiting
> 0739f3815ad8: Waiting
> 7c7b75d0baf8: Waiting
> docker: error pulling image configuration: Get https://production.cloudflare.docker.com/registry-v2/docker/registry/v2/blobs/sha256/02/021a1b85e6419a1ea6d5d00653521b25fcc35e17c2eba2cedadc744e610bf367/data?verify=1610367183-xPQwXESF%2BkbYZOLrfofoZGScHyA%3D: EOF.
> See 'docker run --help'.

I am running on `Windows 10` with a `Kali Linux Subsystem`.. Can anybody help?

Comment: Are you able to pull another image? For example `docker run --rm -it alpine`

Comment: So I just tried to ran it and this is what I got                                                                                   >Unable to find image 'alpine:latest' locally latest: Pulling from library/alpine
>801bfaa63ef2: Already exists
>Digest: >sha256:3c7497bf0c7af93428242d6176e8f7905f2201d8fc5861f45be7a346b5f2343>6
>Status: Downloaded newer image for alpine:latest

>/ #
>/ #